# Custom ListAdapter Issue

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Using [this](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview) I tried to create a custom ListAdapter that would simply add all my records as CheckBoxes.  Even though I can see during debug that the adapter contains all 4 expected records and the override int Count method returns 4 and the override View GetView iterates through 4 times, the position variable always = 0 and only 1 CheckBox containing the first record actually shows up.

ListView row layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

CallManager.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/equipLayout"
      android:tag="equip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/place4"
      android:layout_margin="8dip"
      android:visibility="gone">
     <ListView
      android:id="@+id/equipLV"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//There are several other nested LinearLayouts which is why I have the ScrollView and RelativeLayouts.  Not relevant so left out for cleanliness.

CallManagement.cs

```
public class CallManagement : Activity
{      
    CustomListAdapter listAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CallManager);

        ListView equipLV = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.equipLV);
        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, callNumber.Substring(0,10));
        equipLV.Adapter = listAdapter;

}
```

Custom ListAdapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Activity context;
    External inst;

    public List<equip> equip;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, string callNumber)
        :base()
    {
        inst = new External();
        this.context = context;
        this.equip = new List<equip>();
        this.equip = inst.popEquipLV().ToList();                            
    }

    public override int  Count
    {
        get { return equip.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object  GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long  GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View  GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = equip[position];
        var view = (convertView ?? 
            context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.equipLVitem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

        CheckBox checkItem = (CheckBox)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkItem);
        checkItem.Tag = GetItemAtPosition(position).unit.ToString();
        checkItem.Text = GetItemAtPosition(position).serial.ToString();

        return view;
    }

    public equip GetItemAtPosition(int position)
    {
        return equip[position];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever want to put a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Removing the ScrollView seems to have worked, but what if I need the ScrollView? Is there no way to make those two things work together?

Comment: Nope. How is it supposed to know what to scroll if you have one scrolling container inside of another and they both scroll in the same direction? What do you need two scroll containers for?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an ArrayAdapter so you don't have as much custom code:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/NotePad-Mono.Data.Sqlite/NoteAdapter.cs